# Incredibuild not handling custom build tools very well

Tags: linker, visual-studio-2015, incredibuild

I have a Visual Studio solution which I'm trying to build using the Incredibuild tool. Two of the projects in the solution work in tandem - the first project (we'll call it "Project A") builds an executable (foo.exe) which can parse a data file in the second ("Project B") to generate some header files.

Obviously there is a dependency on Project A defined in Project B. If I use Incredibuild's Rebuild Project option on Project B, it correctly builds Project A and foo.exe is successfully built. Project B has a custom build tool file which should cause foo.exe to be ran with a command-line argument to the file it's supposed to parse. However, trying to launch foo.exe in this way always returns an error:

> CustomBuild:
>
> Running Foo
>
> '*path to executable*\foo.exe' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5):
>   error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009.

Interestingly, if I then use Incredibuild to build *only* Project B (i.e. using the Build Project option), everything is ok - it correctly picks foo.exe from the location it was built to on the previous, failed, build. This makes me think that the path, at least, must be ok.

**Can anyone suggest why the executable cannot be ran as part of the rebuild**? Is it a timing issue, e.g. Project B commences before foo.exe is known to the file system??

It all works under Visual Studio's regular (re)build. It's just the Incredibuild rebuild which fails. Note that I'm doing all of this through the Visual Studio IDE, not from a command line.

Edit: this is the freebie version of Incredibuild that I'm using (the one which comes with Visual Studio), so all of the build is on the local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the Xoreax technical support about this in the end and they told me that this is a "*rare but known issue that is related to one of our extra accelerating features*".

Their first suggestion was writing an executable which simply sleeps "for a few milliseconds" and having that run as part of the custom build tool post-link. This did indeed solve the immediate problem, but the solution I'm building has numerous similar problems and adding this delay in everywhere quickly became tedious and didn't always work. It felt like a fudge anyhow.

So I asked if this behaviour can be toggled to off, and indeed it can. In Visual Studio the Incredibuild menu has an Agent Settings option, and from the invoked dialog's Visual Studio Builds|Advanced page it's a simple case of unchecking the **Enhance throughput using out-of-order tasks spawning** option.

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

There are options how to offload or intercept custom tools during your build process. Try to look onto "c:\program files (x86)\IncrediBuild\Samples"